# error when parsing with sql xmltable with utf-8 encoding in the XML header

Tags: xml, db2, db2-400, xmltable

I am trying to parse and xml string with utf-8 in the xml header using db2 xmltable function.  If I remove the utf-8 everything runs great, but if I leave it in I get SQLSTATE 2200M error.  What am I missing?  I should note that I'm running this on IBM i v7.2 and on 7.3

```
select * from xmltable(XMLNamespaces( DEFAULT 'IBA/FIXML-5-0-SP2'),                                                
'$d/FIXML/MktDataInc/Inc/SprdBnchmkCurve'                            
passing xmlparse(document                                            
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
 <FIXML xmlns="IBA/FIXML-5-0-SP2" v="FIX.5.0SP2" xv="167" cv="IBA"   
 s="2013-10-14">                                                     
 <MktDataInc TrdDt="2018-06-19">                                     
 <Inc UpdtAct="0" Typ="3" Tm="10:55:05">                             
   <SprdBnchmkCurve Ccy="USD" Name="LIBOR" Point="12M" Px="2.7625"   
 PxTyp="24" />                                                       
   </Inc>                                                            
 <Inc UpdtAct="0" Typ="3" Tm="10:55:05">                             
   <SprdBnchmkCurve Ccy="USD" Name="LIBOR" Point="1M" Px="2.08788"   
 PxTyp="24" />                                                       
   </Inc> </MktDataInc>                                              
            </FIXML> ' ) as "d"
columns POINT char(2) path '@Point', 
cur_val char(10) path '@Px'          
) x
```

Comment: The code you posted runs OK for me (on Db2 11.1.3.3), both from the CLP and from Data Studio. I'm not sure what your issue is. I do get `SQL0445W  Value "12M" has been truncated.` as your `char(2)` is too short, but no `SQLSTATE 2200M: A value failed to parse as a well-formed XML document or validate according to the XML schema.` error

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the reason `encoding="utf-8"` doesn't work is that the string constant is not `utf-8` within IBM i, it is EBCDIC. If you were parsing a file from the IFS, that could be in utf-8 format.

Comment: That was the issue.  I was able to directly read from the IFS file using get_xml_file

Answer (score 0):

You really should be looking at the error message associated with the SQLCode.  When I run the statement using Run SQL Scripts, I get the following error, which clearly indicates that the error type is 7, meaning that internal coding does not match the external coding.

[image: Error Message]

As jmarkmurphy said, the data is EBCDIC, but you are saying it is UTF-8.   If you really want UTF-8, you can cast the data to UTF-8 for it to work.

```
select * from xmltable(XMLNamespaces( DEFAULT 'IBA/FIXML-5-0-SP2'),                                                
'$d/FIXML/MktDataInc/Inc/SprdBnchmkCurve'                            
passing xmlparse(document                                            
 CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
 <FIXML xmlns="IBA/FIXML-5-0-SP2" v="FIX.5.0SP2" xv="167" cv="IBA"   
 s="2013-10-14">                                                     
 <MktDataInc TrdDt="2018-06-19">                                     
 <Inc UpdtAct="0" Typ="3" Tm="10:55:05">                             
   <SprdBnchmkCurve Ccy="USD" Name="LIBOR" Point="12M" Px="2.7625"   
 PxTyp="24" />                                                       
   </Inc>                                                            
 <Inc UpdtAct="0" Typ="3" Tm="10:55:05">                             
   <SprdBnchmkCurve Ccy="USD" Name="LIBOR" Point="1M" Px="2.08788"   
 PxTyp="24" />                                                       
   </Inc> </MktDataInc>                                              
            </FIXML> ' AS CLOB(1M) CCSID 1208)) as "d"
columns POINT char(2) path '@Point', 
cur_val char(10) path '@Px'          
) x   ;
```